# How likely is a Split Brain situation when dealing with Galera clusters?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, galera

Assuming I have a server setup where a quorum vote is always satisfied, how likely will a Split Brain situation occur with Galera? My understanding is Galera does its best to avoid it, but does that mean there's 0 chance of it ever happening if the servers and MySQL/MariaDB processes never fail?

If it's a real possibility, is there a best practice for proper recovery?

Comment: This Q should be moved to dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have a 3-node system with no weightings and the nodes are in separate geographical locations?

Split brain usually happens when these *two* things occur:

1. One node dies, and before you can get it repaired,...
2. The network between the two other nodes dies.  Now neither of those nodes will accept writes because neither has a quorum.

Hence no "split brain", but instead a read-only system.

The simple answer is that "quorum" prevents "split brain".